# image_transport rosbag issue

Tags: ros, rosbag, image-transport, compressed-image-transport, pointgrey

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone else seen problems recording rosbags for all topics of a node using image_transport?

> ERROR
> [/tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-compressed-depth-image-transport-1.9.2-0trusty-20150729-0539/src/compressed_depth_publisher.cpp:223(CompressedDepthPublisher::publish)
>
> ...
>
> Compressed Depth Image Transport -Compression requires single-channel 32bit-floating point or 16bit raw depth images (input format is: bgr8).

I see this with [pointgrey_camera_driver (tag 0.12.1)](https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver.git) when doing a `rosbag record -a`. I've noticed some [issues](https://github.com/ros-drivers/axis_camera/issues/32) posted for other packages using image_transport so I thought I'd post a general question in the event there is some broader issue.

UPDATE:
Running `rosbag record -a -x "(.*)/compressed(.*)"` solves the issue of the errors by not recording the "compressed" topics but doesn't explain why they occur in the first place.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251403/image_transport-rosbag-issue/) by [roboticom314](https://answers.ros.org/users/26759/roboticom314/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2017-01-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robot_commander](https://answers.ros.org/users/29498/robot_commander/) on 2018-01-29**:
Hi, I'm also facing the same issue.

**Comment by [Farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25360/farid/) on 2020-08-19**:
I get this error running my android phone with ip address with `IP webcam` App and `video_stream_opencv` package!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that the normal image is processed by an `image_transport` plugin that normally expects depth images only, after the topic `*compressedDepth*` is first subscribed, e.g. by `rosbag record -a`.

I solved the issue for me by disabling the plugin as described in the answer to this question: https://answers.ros.org/question/255970 (and here: https://github.com/ros-drivers/usb_cam/issues/55).
The topics that produce the errors then disappear, and I can safely record everything without triggering these errors.

The launch file I've ended up using roughly goes like this:

```
<launch>
    <group ns="camera/front">
        <!-- launch camera -->
        <node pkg="libuvc_camera" type="camera_node" name="camera_node">
            <!-- parameters here -->
        </node>

        <!-- disable compressed depth plugin for image transport -->
        <group ns="image_raw">
            <rosparam param="disable_pub_plugins">
              - 'image_transport/compressedDepth'
            </rosparam>
        </group>
    </group>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [moooeeeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/27965/moooeeeep/) with karma: 194 on 2018-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0